# Coq: Proving that the product of n and (S n) is even

Tags: functional-programming, coq

Given the procedure `even`, I want to prove that `even (n * (S n)) = true` for all natural numbers `n`.

Using induction, this is easily seen to be `true` for the case `n = 0`. However, the case `(S n) * (S (S n))` is hard to simplify.

I've considered proving the lemma that `even (m * n) = even m /\ even n`, but this doesn't seem to be easier.

Also, it is easy to see that if `even n = true` iff. `even (S n) = false`.

```
Fixpoint even (n: nat) : bool :=
  match n with
  | O => true
  | 1 => false
  | S (S n') => even n'
  end.
```

Can someone give a hint on how to prove this using a "beginner's" subset of Coq?

Comment: I would start proving that `even n -> even (n * m)` (for all `m`). Then since `even n <-> (even (S n) = false)` and `n*m = m*n` you should be able to prove that `even (n * (S n))`. Not sure whether this simplies anything though...

Comment: Do you think "even n -> even (n * m)" would be easy to prove?

Comment: Maybe. consider that: `n * (S m') = n + n * m'` by inductive hypothesis `n*m'` is even and `even n /\ even m -> even (n+m)` which yields the thesis.

Comment: Thanks, but then "even (n + m)" seems hard to prove (although easy at first sight).

Comment: Why? If `n = O` then using `simpl` gets you `n+m = m` which is even by hypothesis. If `n = (S (S n'))` then using `simpl` you get `S (S (n' + m))` which by inductive hypothesis + the fact that `even n <-> even (S ( S n))` yields the thesis. You just need `even n -> (n = O \/ n = S (S n') /\ even n')` which doesn't seem hard to prove inductively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another version, in the spirit of @ejgallego's answer.
Let's give another definition for the even predicate. The purpose of this is to make proofs by simple induction easy, so there is no need of using `pair_induction`. The main idea is that we are going to prove some properties of `even2` and then we'll use the fact that `Nat.even` and `even2` are extensionally equal to transfer the properties of `even2` onto `Nat.even`.

```
Require Import Coq.Bool.Bool.

Fixpoint even2 (n : nat) : bool :=
  match n with
  | O => true
  | S n' => negb (even2 n')
  end.
```

Let's show that `Nat.even` and `even2` are extensionally equal.

```
Lemma even_S n :
  Nat.even (S n) = negb (Nat.even n).
Proof. induction n; auto. apply negb_sym; assumption. Qed.

Lemma even_equiv_even2 n :
  Nat.even n = even2 n.
Proof. induction n; auto. now rewrite even_S, IHn. Qed.
```

Some distribution lemmas for `even2`:

```
Lemma even2_distr_add m n :
  even2 (m + n) = negb (xorb (even2 m) (even2 n)).
Proof.
  induction m; simpl.
  - now destruct (even2 n).
  - rewrite IHm. now destruct (even2 m); destruct (even2 n).
Qed.

Lemma even2_distr_mult m n :
  even2 (m * n) = even2 m || even2 n.
Proof.
  induction m; auto; simpl.
  rewrite even2_distr_add, IHm.
  now destruct (even2 m); destruct (even2 n).
Qed.
```

Finally, we are able to prove our goal, using the equality between `Nat.even` and `even2`.

```
Goal forall n, Nat.even (n * (S n)) = true.
  intros n.
  now rewrite even_equiv_even2, even2_distr_mult, orb_negb_r.
Qed.
```

Comment: I'm in deep trouble proving "even_add_even". I've attached my partial proof in the question. Here "nat_ind2" is your "pair_induction". 
Can you give me a hint how to proceed?

Comment: `simpl. rewrite IH_m'. reflexivity. simpl in H. apply H.`

Answer (score 5):

This is a case where a more advanced induction principle can be useful. It is briefly described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40595110/2747511).

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
Require Import Coq.Bool.Bool.    

Lemma pair_induction (P : nat -> Prop) :
  P 0 -> P 1 -> (forall n, P n -> P (S n) -> P (S (S n))) ->
  forall n, P n.
Proof.
  intros ? ? ? n. enough (P n /\ P (S n)) by tauto.
  induction n; intuition.
Qed.
```

Now, let's define several helper lemmas. They are obvious and can be easily proved using the `pair_induction` principle and some proof automation.

```
Lemma even_mul2 : forall n, Nat.even (2 * n) = true.
Proof.
  induction n; auto.
  now replace (2 * S n) with (2 + 2 * n) by ring.
Qed.

Lemma even_add_even : forall m n,
  Nat.even m = true ->
  Nat.even (m + n) = Nat.even n.
Proof.
  now induction m using pair_induction; auto.
Qed.

Lemma even_add_mul2 : forall m n,
  Nat.even (2 * m + n) = Nat.even n.
Proof.
  intros; apply even_add_even, even_mul2.
Qed.

Lemma even_S : forall n,
  Nat.even (S n) = negb (Nat.even n).
Proof.
  induction n; auto.
  simpl (Nat.even (S (S n))).   (* not necessary -- just to make things clear *)
  apply negb_sym. assumption.
Qed.
```

The following lemma shows how to "distribute" `even` over multiplication. It plays an important role in the proof of our main goal. As almost always generalization helps a lot.

```
Lemma even_mult : forall m n,
  Nat.even (m * n) = Nat.even m || Nat.even n.
Proof.
  induction m using pair_induction; simpl; auto.
  intros n. replace (n + (n + m * n)) with (2 * n + m * n) by ring.
  now rewrite even_add_mul2.
Qed.
```

Now, the proof of the goal is trivial

```
Goal forall n, Nat.even (n * (S n)) = true.
  intros n. now rewrite even_mult, even_S, orb_negb_r.
Qed.
```

> Can someone give a hint on how to prove this using a "beginner's" subset of Coq?

You can consider this a hint, since it reveals the general structure of a possible proof. The automatic tactics may be replaced by the "manual" tactics like  with `rewrite`, `apply`, `destruct` and so on.

Comment: What is orb in the proof?

Comment: Is pair induction really needed?

Comment: (1) You can issue this query: `Print orb.` to check what it is. It's boolean "or". Of course you can do it without pair induction -- remember, it's user-defined, it's not some hidden Coq mechanism. It's just a method of strengthening the induction hypothesis.

Comment: @Shuzheng I've simplified the proof of the goal. The proofs could be simpler if you defined `even` as `Fixpoint even (n: nat) : bool :=
  match n with
  | O => true | S n' => negb (even n') end.`

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to contribute a shorter proof using the mathcomp lib:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect all_algebra.

Lemma P n : ~~ odd (n * n.+1).
Proof. by rewrite odd_mul andbN. Qed.
```

`odd_mul` is proved by simple induction, as well as `odd_add`.

Comment: The definition of `odd` here has different structure comparing to `even` in the question, that's why simple induction works well in this case.

Answer (score 2):

A short version that makes use of the standard library:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Goal forall n, Nat.even (n * (S n)) = true.
  intros n.
  now rewrite Nat.even_mul, Nat.even_succ, Nat.orb_even_odd.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here is my take on the solution. The essential idea is, instead of proving a predicate `P n`, prove instead `P n /\ P (S n)`, which is equivalent, but the second formulation allows to use simple induction.

Here is the complete proof:

```
Require Import Nat.
Require Import Omega.

Definition claim n := even (n * (S n)) = true.

(* A technical Lemma, needed in the proof *)
Lemma tech: forall n m, even n = true -> even (n + 2*m) = true.
Proof.
  intros. induction m.
  * simpl. replace (n+0) with n; intuition.
  * replace (n + 2 * S m) with (S (S (n+2*m))); intuition.
Qed.

(* A simple identity, that Coq needs help to prove *)
Lemma ident: forall n, 
    (S (S n) * S (S (S n))) = (S n * S( S n) + 2*(S (S n))).
    (* (n+2)*(n+3) = (n+1)*(n+2) + 2*(n+2) *)
Proof.
  intro.
  replace (S (S (S n))) with ((S n) + 2) by intuition.
  remember (S (S n)) as m.
  replace (m * (S n + 2)) with ((S n + 2) * m) by intuition.
  intuition.
Qed.

(* The claim to be proved by simple induction *)
Lemma nsn: forall n, claim n /\ claim (S n).
Proof.
  intros.
  unfold claim.
  induction n.
  *  intuition.
  *  intuition. rewrite ident. apply tech; auto.
Qed.     

(* The final result is now a simple corollary *)
Theorem thm: forall n, claim n.
Proof.
  apply nsn.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a nice proof :-)