# Can I tell Coq to do induction from n to n+2?

Tags: coq, induction

I'm trying to see if it's possible to prove `evenb n = true <-> exists k, n = double k` from https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Logic.html without involving odd numbers at all. I tried something like the following:

```
Theorem evenb_double_k : forall n,
  evenb n = true -> exists k, n = double k.
Proof.
  intros n H. induction n as [|n' IHn'].
  - exists 0. reflexivity.
  - (* stuck *)
```

But apparently induction works one natural number at a time, and `exists k : nat, S n' = double k` is clearly not provable.

```
n' : nat
H : evenb (S n') = true
IHn' : evenb n' = true -> exists k : nat, n' = double k
______________________________________(1/1)
exists k : nat, S n' = double k
```

Is there a way to have induction go from n to n+2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a tactic called `fix`. I will try to explain what is happening at a high level, because I think it is a cool hack, but be warned that `fix` is a double-edged sword, generally ill advised to use: it depends on really low-level details of Coq, that make proofs quite fragile, and when they break, the error messages are difficult to understand.

`fix foo i`, where `foo` is a fresh variable, and `i` is an integer, is a tactic which applies to a goal with at least `i` arguments (for example, `forall n, evenb n = true -> ...` has two: `n` and a proof of `evenb n = true`), and **assumes the goal that you are trying to prove**, naming that new hypothesis `foo`. (Yes, you read that right.)

```
Theorem evenb_double_k : forall n,
  evenb n = true -> exists k, n = double k.
Proof.
  fix self 1.

(*

1 subgoal (ID 17)

  self : forall n : nat,
         evenb n = true -> exists k : nat, n = double k
  ============================
  forall n : nat, evenb n = true -> exists k : nat, n = double k

 *)
```

Of course, there is a catch: **that hypothesis must be applied to a proper subterm of `n`** (which is the *first* argument of the goal, that's what the number parameter of `fix self 1` means, we say that the first argument is the *decreasing argument*). What is a proper subterm of `n`? It is a value that you can get only by destructing `n`, at least once.

Note that Coq won't immediately complain if you still decide to apply the hypothesis `self` directly (`n` is not a proper subterm of itself). Coq only checks the "subterm" requirement on `Qed`. *EDIT*: You can also use the command `Guarded` at any time to check this.

```
  apply self. (* seems fine, all goals done. *)
Qed. (* ERROR! *)
```

You can approximatively imagine `fix` as a form of strong induction, where the induction hypothesis (`self`) is given for all terms smaller than the current one, not only immediate predecessors. However this "subterm" relation does not actually appear in the statement of `self`. (This peculiarity is what makes `fix` a low-level, dangerous tactic.)

After a `fix` you generally want to `destruct` the decreasing argument. This is where `fix` allows your proof to follow the structure of `evenb`. Below, we destruct again immediately in the `S` case. So we get three cases: `n = O`, `n = S O`, `n = S (S n')` for some `n' : nat`.

The first case is easy, the second one is vacuous, and the third one is where you need the "induction hypothesis" `self` at `n'`.

```
Proof.
  fix self 1.
  intros n.
  destruct n as [| [| n']].
  - exists 0; reflexivity.
  - discriminate.
  - simpl. intro H.
    apply self in H.
    destruct H as [k Hk].
    exists (S k).
    rewrite Hk; reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Some of the reasoning there is fairly generic, and it can be pulled out into a custom *induction principle for even `nat`s*, which is concretely another `Theorem`.

```
Theorem even_ind :
  forall (P : nat -> Prop),
    P O ->
    (forall n, evenb n = true -> P n -> P (S (S n))) ->
    forall n, evenb n = true -> P n.
```

Compare it to the standard induction principle for `nat`, which is in fact also a theorem, named `nat_ind`. This is what the `induction` tactic uses under the hood.

```
About nat_ind.

(* nat_ind :
     forall P : nat -> Prop,
       P 0 ->
       (forall n : nat, P n -> P (S n)) ->
       forall n : nat, P n
 *)
```

The induction step in `nat_ind` goes from `n` to `S n`, whereas the induction step for `even_ind` goes from `n` to `S (S n)`, and has an extra hypothesis saying that our numbers are even.

The proof of `even_ind` follows a similar structure to `evenb_double_k`, although it is more abstract because it generalizes over all predicates `P` on `nat`.

```
Proof.
  intros P HO HSS.
  fix self 1.
  intros n.
  destruct n as [| [| n']].
  - intro; apply HO.
  - discriminate.
  - intros H. apply HSS.
    + apply H.
    + apply self.
      apply H.
Qed.
```

Another approach here is to not use `fix` at all (since it should be avoided), but keep `induction` as a primitive to prove the alternative `even_ind` principle. That is fine for `nat`, but for some complex inductive types, the default induction principle is too weak and a handwritten `fix` is the only way.

Finally, going back to `evenb_double_k`, we can use the new induction principle with `apply even_ind`, as opposed to `fix` or `induction`. We now get only the two meaningful cases, `O` and `S (S n')` where `n'` is even.

```
Theorem evenb_double_k' : forall n,
  evenb n = true -> exists k, n = double k.
Proof.
  apply even_ind.
  - exists 0. reflexivity.
  - intros n H [k Hk].
    exists (S k).
    rewrite Hk.
    reflexivity.
Qed.
```

---

Definitions used in this answer:

```
Fixpoint evenb n :=
  match n with
  | S (S n') => evenb n'
  | S O => false
  | O => true
  end.

Fixpoint double k :=
  match k with
  | O => O
  | S k' => S (S (double k'))
  end.
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. As with the other answer, I'm not familiar enough with Coq to understand every step yet, but I liked the idea of extracting the even_ind theorem and that it doesn't involve odd numbers at all.

Comment: I think it's good to know that you can use `Guarded.` during the proof to early verify that your proof satisfy the "subterm" requirement.

Comment: Oh yes I totally forgot about it but that's definitely very useful!

Comment: Wow fix is amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Yes, absolutely! Let's use the induction principle from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40595110/2747511).

```
From Coq Require Import Arith.

Lemma pair_induction (P : nat -> Prop) :
  P 0 -> P 1 ->
  (forall n, P n -> P (S n) -> P (S (S n))) ->
  forall n, P n.
Proof.
  intros H0 H1 Hstep n.
  enough (P n /\ P (S n)) by easy.
  induction n; intuition.
Qed.
```

Now we can use the new principle like so (I switched the non-standard functions with their stdlib counterparts so that everything compiles):

```
Theorem evenb_double_k : forall n,
  Nat.even n = true -> exists k, n = Nat.double k.
Proof.
  intros n Ev.
  induction n as [| |n IHn _] using pair_induction.
  (* the rest of the proof has been removed to not spoil the fun *)
Qed.
```

Comment: I still need time to understand the lemma but the proof worked beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: We strengthened the new inductive step compared to the regular induction principle: to prove that a predicate holds of some number you will have two helper hypotheses saying that the predicate holds of the two immediate predecessors of the number. But we have to pay for this strengthening by having more proof obligations -- we have two base cases to get induction going. Intuitively, you start with `P 0` and `P 1` and produces `P 2`, then we can use `P 1` and `P 2` to get `P 3` and so on and so forth. If e.g. one only has `P 0` and doesn't have `P 1`, then one can't use the step to get `P 2`.